# How to replace a value in a Specific Location in arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a Contact List array it contains Name and phone Number and status . I show it in a list view. In first case the all the staus value is zero when i click the list view i want to change the status to 1. How to do it.

My contact class with Getter and Setters

```
public class Contact {

    private String Name;
    private String PhoneNo;
    private String Status;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return PhoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        PhoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }


}
```

I define the arraylist using this class as

```
  ArrayList<"Contact"> _ArrayList = new ArrayList<"Contact">();
```

i add values as

```
  Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setName("User1");
    contact.setPhoneNo("956375369");
    contact.setStatus(1);
    _ArrayList.add(contact);
```

So i want to replace the status value. Thanx in advance

Comment: Please show your listview code.

Comment: You need assign `OnItemClickListener` over your `ListView`. Then when you click on Item you know position you clicked and at this position, update item in List and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to send request to update `ListView` itself.

Comment: You can use map to store the values as key --> Contact and values --> "status and phoneno". Use map.get(clicked_element_contact) and update the status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I guess there was a typo in the below line.

```
ArrayList<Contact> _ArrayList = new ArrayList<Contact>(); // Contact should be without double quotes.
```

Next, you can use the [`List#get(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method to get the element at a particular index.

**E.g:** I'm using the example index as *0*. You can use the index as per your reqt.

```
ArrayList.get(0).setStatus(2); // Change the status of the element at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way is to iterate over the array list to identify the correct user whose status has to be changed. Something like below:

```
for(Contact contactObj: _ArrayList){

if (contactObj.getName().equals("User1")){
contactObj.setStatus(-1);
}

}
```

Here it will iterate over the list of contacts, to match and find contact with name "User1" and change its status to -2

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

        _ArrayList.get(position).setStatus(0); // Change status of clicked list row
   }
});
```

Here listView is object of ListView...

Hope this will solve your problem.